# Нужно сделать своеобразный счетчик очков

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

1. Есть файл на сервере в котором записано число.
2. На сайте есть кнопки +10 + 50 + 100 при нажатии на которые указанное число прибавляется к тому, что уже записано в файле. Важно, чтобы страница при этом не перезагружалась.
3. Далее финальное число это выводится на сайт.

Вроде бы все решил задачу по всем пункта (ниже). Но не могу допереть как во втором пункте сделать так, чтобы страница не перезагружалась.
Второй пункт:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['like'])) {

$file = file_get_contents('score_cmdtwo.php');
$fp = fopen('score_cmdtwo.php', 'w+');
$add_rate = fwrite($fp, $file + 1);
fclose($fp);
echo $file;

}

?>
```

Третий пункт

```
<script>  
    function show()  
    {  
        $.ajax({  
            url: "score_cmdtwo.php",  
            cache: false,  
            success: function(html){  
                $("#cmdtwo").html(html);  
            }  
        });  
    }  

    $(document).ready(function(){  
        show();  
        setInterval('show()',1000);  
    });  
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Как минимум нужно в запросе в поле data указать новое значение, которое нужно отправить на сервер. Указать type ( GET или POST ) Если нажимаешь +10 то засылай 10 и т.д.